# Mutate new variable by condition

Tags: r, purrr, dplyr

I am trying to mutate a new variable inside a list. I got two variables called rci_det_post coded with 1/0 and a variable called rci_imp_post coded also as 1/0. I want to mutate a new variable which contains -1 when rci_det_post is 1 and 1 when rci_imp_post is 1. If both are 0 it should contain 0.

Here is an example how I want it too look like:

```
      rci_det_post  rci_imp_post rci.1
1           1           0          -1                                                  
2           0           0           0                                                  
3           0           1           1                                       
4           0           0           0
```

So I tried this:

```
implist %>%
  map(function(x) mutate(x, rci.1 = ifelse(x$rci_det_post == 1 & x$rci_imp_post == 0, -1,
                                           ifelse(x$rci_det_post == 0 & x$rci_imp_pst == 1, 1,
                                                  ifelse(x$rci_det_post == 0 & rci_imp_post == 0, 0)))))
```

But unfortunatly it is not working, because I get this in return:

```
      rci_det_post  rci_imp_post rci.1
1           1           0          -1                                                  
2           0           0           NA                                                  
3           0           1           NA                                       
4           0           0           NA
```

Can someone help me with that one?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer of Sotos

```
#using ifelse
implist$rci.1 <- ifelse(implist$rci_det_post ==1, -1,
                        ifelse(implist$rci_imp_post == 1, 1,
                               ifelse(implist$rci_det_post == 0 & implist$rci_imp_post == 0, 0, implist$rci.1)))

#using data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(implist)
implist[rci_det_post == 1, rci.1 := -1]
implist[rci_imp_post == 1, rci.1 := 1]
implist[rci_det_post ==0 & rci_imp_post == 0, rci.1 := 0]
```

Notice that in the last line of your ifelse function you only defined what the value should be when both variables equal to 0

```
ifelse(x$rci_det_post == 0 & rci_imp_post == 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overthinking it. If you only have binary values then you can make use of `pmax` to get the max value of each row. That will be either 1 or 0 (if both 0). you can then apply a condition to change all values where `rci_det_post` is 1, to -1, i.e.

```
replace(do.call(pmax, d1), d1$rci_det_post == 1, -1)
#[1] -1  0  1  0
```

where

```
dput(d1)
structure(list(rci_det_post = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), rci_imp_post = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering. 

I think I dont quite understand the solution. The problem is that tehre are also alot of other variables so the pmax isn't working. Also I dont quite understand what the second part with d1 ist doing. Sorry I am quite new to this topic.

Comment: If you have other columns then do it on the columns you need, i.e. `do.call(pmax, d1[2:3])` If the columns of interest are second and third. The second part (with the `dput`) is just to make the example reproducible for people to simply copy/paste in their session. Nothing to do with the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  mutate(rci.1 = case_when(
    rci_det_post == 1 ~ -1,
    rci_imp_post == 1 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )
)
```

Is it possible that both variable are 1 at same time? If so this will give such a row value -1.